# Not able to login to concourse from GUI

Tags: concourse, concourse-pipeline, vault

I have installed concourse ci with integration vault and database postgress SQL using below link.
Done with all the steps given in below link and all 4 docker container is working fine .
https://spr.com/how-to-automate-data-protection-using-concourse-ci-and-hashicorp-vault/

But when I click on the login button in concourse GUI shown in below image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBgoB.png)

I am getting below error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EF9D0.png)

Note : vault is working fine and I am able to store and retrieve the credentials from command line using (vault kv get/put )

But I am not able to go ahead in concourse login and I have also tried with fly.

I am new into concourse , Could you please suggest me why am i getting this error , any solution for it ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't set the `CONCOURSE_EXTERNAL_URL` variable. When that's not set, it will do all login work through `http://localhost:8080`. How you set that variable depends on how it's deployed (BOSH vs k8s vs docker compose).